# Proving that a vector-valued function is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

> > Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be open. A function $\varphi: \Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ is differentiable at $\underline{a} \in \Omega$ if and only if there exists a linear map $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^p$ such that $$\lim\limits_{\underline{h}\to \underline{0}} \frac{1}{\|\underline{h}\|}\|\varphi(\underline{a}+\underline{h})-\varphi(\underline{a})-T(\underline{h})\|=0$$
> >     In such a case, $T$ is called the differential of $\varphi$ at $\underline{a}$, denoted by $d\varphi(\underline{a}).$
>
> Suppose $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are differentiable at $\underline{a}$. Let $\begin{bmatrix}
>          \varphi \\
>          \psi \\
>         \end{bmatrix}$ denote the map from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2p}$ given by $$\begin{bmatrix}
>          \varphi \\
>          \psi \\
>         \end{bmatrix}(\underline{x})=\begin{bmatrix}\varphi(\underline{x}) \\ \psi(\underline{x}) \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
>   Prove that this map is differentiable at $\underline{a}$, and find its differential at $\underline{a}$.

I also have an equivalent definition of differentiability that I may use, involving $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, but this one seemed the most straightforward - before I started, at least.

Let $T$ and $S$ be the differentials of $\varphi$ and $\psi$ at $\underline{a}$ (respectively). Define $V:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2p}$ by $$V(\underline{x})=\begin{bmatrix}T(\underline{x}) \\ S(\underline{x}) \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

I suspect that $V$ is the differential I need. I simply need to show that $$\lim\limits_{\underline{h}\to \underline{0}} \frac{1}{\|\underline{h}\|}\|\begin{bmatrix}\varphi(\underline{a}+\underline{h})-\varphi(\underline{a})-T(\underline{h}) \\ \psi(\underline{a}+\underline{h})-\psi(\underline{a})-S(\underline{h}) \\ \end{bmatrix}\|=0$$

This is where I'm not sure how to proceed. I'm convinced that since each part of this vector goes to $0$ in the limit (using definition of differentiability), its norm will also go to $0$, giving me what I need. However, this doesn't sound too rigorous; should I switch from limits to the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use continuity of the norm to pull the limit inside, you get

$$\left\lVert \begin{pmatrix}
\lim_{h\to 0}{\varphi(\underline{a}+\underline{h})-\varphi(\underline{a})-T(\underline{h}) \over \lVert h\rVert}\\
\lim_{h\to 0} {\psi(\underline{a}+\underline{h})-\psi(\underline{a})-S(\underline{h})\over\lVert h\rVert}\end{pmatrix}\right\rVert=0$$

because both components go to $0$ by the definition of $\varphi,\psi$ being differentiable with derivatives $T,S$ (respectively).

This is the definition of $V$ being the differential you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for that. It was such a silly step I was missing, too